# Counting in mod

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

> Arnold, Riaz and Topaz are counting from $1$ to $999$,
> Arnold, then Riaz and Topaz. For example: Arnold counts $1$,
> Riaz counts $2$, Topaz counts $3$, Arnold counts $4$, and
> until Topaz finally calls $999$.
>
> If the number $a$ which they count satisfies $a^{b} \equiv b
>  \pmod{a+b}$ for any integer $1<= b<= 10$, they get $a$ points, else
> they do'nt receive any points. If at the end of the game, Arnold has
> $k$ points, Riaz has $r$ points and Topaz has $t$ points, find the
> value of $|k-r|+|k-t|+|t-r|$.

Uptil now:
$a\equiv -b\ (\bmod a+b)$
$a^{b} \equiv ( -b)^{b} \ (\bmod a+b)$

In the question, wee know that $a^{b} \equiv b\ (\bmod a+b)$, so
$b\equiv ( -b)^{b} \ (\bmod a+b)$.

I dont know how to continue! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can consider expression  $A=\frac{(-b)^b-b}{a+b}$ for all cases of $b$: $b=1$, $A=\frac{-2}{a+1}$ it is integer only for $a=1$. $b=2$, $A=\frac{2}{a+2}$, which cannot be integer for positive integer $a$. And so on.

Comment: Ugly problem that bends to a calculator fairly easily.  For $b \in \{1,2,\cdots,10\}$, compute $R_b = (-b)^b - b.$  Then, compute the complete prime factorization for each $R_b$.  Suppose that $d$ divides $R_b$.  Then one of the values of $a$ which will score a point, for this particular value of $b$ is $(a = d-b)$.  So, via a computer, you can form a complete list of all values of $a$, such that $a$ scores a point on any of the values of $b$.